# How to call a 3rd party REST API again based on the response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

I want to call a 3rd part REST API from my MVC web application. I can successfully get a response and also able to process the JSON response. But the response itself has links to a different URL for the same API.
Any better way of handling that in C#?  i.e if I get a url as response I want to call the API again using that url.

Comment: so build a new request. What´s the problem? Maybe it might help if you provided some sample code that better illustrates your problem.

Comment: What's the problem? You need to make the second API call anyway. You just:
fetch => get response URL => fetch with URL => handle response. If you do this under a single operation, you just await the fetches.